Random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^3$. Expected number of visits and probability of return
I am working with the simple symmetric random walk on  $\mathbb{Z}^3$. Using the Fourier identity I have been able to prove:
$$ P(S_n = 0) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left(\frac{\cos x + \cos y + \cos z}{3}\right)^n \, dx \, dy \, dz $$
and that the expected number of visits to zero $N$ (counting $t=0$) is:
$$E[N] = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left(\frac{3}{3 - \cos x - \cos y - \cos z}\right)\, dx \, dy \, dz$$
Now i am asked to show that the probability that the random walk returns to the origin at least once is given by:
$$1 - \frac{1}{E[N]}$$
I have no clue on how to approach this.

probably not with those identities

There's an elementary approach to the calculation of hitting probabilities of this random walk in the first chapter of P. de la Harpe's "Topics in geometric group theory".

This is a  a general fact about transient Markov chains and the random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^3$ is transient.   Denote by $T_0$ the moment of first return to  the origin.  (The moment $t=0$ is not considered a moment of return.)  This is a random quantity with possible values $2,4,6,\dotsc, \infty$.
The transience of the random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^3$ signifies that $p:=P(T_0<\infty)<1$, i.e., the probability of return  to $0$ is $<1$. This was  proved by George Polya   almost a century ago.
If  we denote by $E(N)$ the expectation of $N$, then
$$ E(N)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(N\geq n)= \sum_{n\geq 1} p^n, $$
where the last  equality follows from the equality $p=P(N\geq 1)$ and the strong Markov principle.
Hence
$$E(N)=\frac{p}{1-p}.$$
This is what you wanted to prove.  Indeed, if $N^*=N+1$ (so  $t=0$ is included), then $E(N^*)=E(N)+1=\frac{1}{1-p}$ and
$$
p=1-\frac{1}{E(N^*)}.
$$
For more details   and proofs the facts claimed  above see section 4.2.3 of these notes.
